# numpy function to aggregate a signal for time?

Tags: python, numpy, signals, pandas

I want to compute the aggregated average of a signal over time, in a certain period. I don't know how this is called scientifically.

Example: I have an electricity consumption for a full year in 15 minute values.  I want to know my average consumption by hour of the day (24 values).  But it is more complex: there are more measurements in between the 15-minute steps, and I cannot foresee where they are.  However, they should be taken into account, with a correct 'weight'.

I wrote a function that works, but it is extremely slow. Here is a test setup:

```
import numpy as np

signal = np.arange(6)
time = np.array([0, 2, 3.5, 4, 6, 8])
period = 4
interval = 2

def aggregate(signal, time, period, interval):
    pass

aggregated = aggregate(signal, time, period, interval)
# This should be the result: aggregated = array([ 2.   ,  3.125])
```

`aggregated` should have `period/interval` values.  This is the manual computation:

```
aggregated[0] = (np.trapz(y=np.array([0, 1]), x=np.array([0, 2]))/interval + \
               np.trapz(y=np.array([3, 4]), x=np.array([4, 6]))/interval) / (period/interval)
aggregated[1] = (np.trapz(y=np.array([1, 2, 3]), x=np.array([2, 3.5, 4]))/interval + \
                np.trapz(y=np.array([4, 5]), x=np.array([6, 8]))/interval) / (period/interval)
```

One last detail: it has to be efficient, thats why my own solution is not useful.  Maybe I'm overlooking a numpy or scipy method?  Or is this something pandas can do? 
Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: I'm finding this tricky to understand. Are the `time` values when the signal points occur? How do the `period` and `interval` values tie in? And I don't get your manual computation, all the `interal` values cancel out. Please try and clarify a bit :)

Comment: I tried to be as clear as possible.  I try to clarify by the example I gave: the `time` values are indeed where the signal occurs, let's suppose it is in seconds.  The `period` would be 86400, and the `interval` would be 3600.  I hope this helps

Comment: cool, what do the `first` and `second` values represent?

Comment: These are the 'physical' calculations of the elements of `aggregated`.  It's messy, but I wanted to show how to understand what the desired result actually means.

Answer (score 4):

I would strongly recommend using Pandas.  Here I'm using version 0.8 (soon to be released). I think this is close to what you want.

```
import pandas as p
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as plt

# Make up some data:
time = p.date_range(start='2011-05-23', end='2012-05-23', freq='min')
watts = np.linspace(0, 3.14 * 365, time.size)
watts = 38 * (1.5 + np.sin(watts)) + 8 * np.sin(5 * watts)

# Create a time series
ts = p.Series(watts, index=time, name='watts')

# Resample down to 15 minute pieces, using mean values
ts15 = ts.resample('15min', how='mean')
ts15.plot()
```

Pandas can easily do many other things with your data (like determine your average weekly energy profile). Check out `p.read_csv()` for reading in your data.

Comment: He'll have to hang tight for the pandas 0.8.0 release

Comment: This is not what I need.  The result of resample() is different from the aggregation I want.  Your example will result in 8640*4 values (one year, 15 minutes interval), while I want to obtain a result of 24*4 values (averaged values by 15min over all days of the year). Does pandas 0.8 have this functionality?

Comment: @sarole Do you want to group by a 24 hr day, split up into the mean value over 15 min increments?

Comment: I think so.  I want to know what is my average value between 00h00 and 00h15, ... for all days in the year (so only 1 value for each time interval).  This will give me 24*4 values.

Comment: Found the answer to my problem and edited this answer in order to make it fully answer the question.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is pretty close to what you need. I'm not sure I interpreted interval and period correctly, but I think I got it write within some constant factor.

```
import numpy as np

def aggregate(signal, time, period, interval):
    assert (period % interval) == 0
    ipp = period / interval

    midpoint = np.r_[time[0], (time[1:] + time[:-1])/2., time[-1]]
    cumsig = np.r_[0, (np.diff(midpoint) * signal).cumsum()]
    grid = np.linspace(0, time[-1], np.floor(time[-1]/period)*ipp + 1)
    cumsig = np.interp(grid, midpoint, cumsig)
    return np.diff(cumsig).reshape(-1, ipp).sum(0) / period
```

Comment: I'm impressed by your function, you teach me advanced numpy use.  My own function had a while and a for loop, and yours is many orders of magnitude faster.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: EDIT: There's something wrong with your function.  I obtain wrong results when applying to long dataseries with irregular time-intervals.  I will try the pandas way.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Pandas, but if it has what you need it's probably going to be easier and more robust than trying to fix my function.

Answer (score 1):

I worked out a function that does exactly what I wanted based on the previous answers and on pandas.

```
def aggregate_by_time(signal, time, period=86400, interval=900, label='left'):
"""
Function to calculate the aggregated average of a timeseries by 
period (typical a day) in bins of interval seconds (default = 900s).

label = 'left' or 'right'.  'Left' means that the label i contains data from 
i till i+1, 'right' means that label i contains data from i-1 till i.    

Returns an array with period/interval values, one for each interval
of the period. 

Note: the period has to be a multiple of the interval

"""

def make_datetimeindex(array_in_seconds, year):
    """
    Create a pandas DateIndex from a time vector in seconds and the year.
    """

    start = pandas.datetime(year, 1, 1)
    datetimes = [start + pandas.datetools.timedelta(t/86400.) for t in array_in_seconds]

    return pandas.DatetimeIndex(datetimes)

interval_string = str(interval) + 'S'    
dr = make_datetimeindex(time, 2012)
df = pandas.DataFrame(data=signal, index=dr, columns=['signal'])
df15min = df.resample(interval_string, closed=label, label=label)

# now create bins for the groupby() method
time_s = df15min.index.asi8/1e9
time_s -= time_s[0]
df15min['bins'] = np.mod(time_s, period)

df_aggr = df15min.groupby(['bins']).mean()

# if you only need the numpy array: take df_aggr.values
return df_aggr
```